# Is it possible to bring Tramadol into Qatar?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, qatar, drugs

Can I bring Tramadol from another country into Qatar? Will Customs take action if I bring Tramadol into Qatar?

Comment: Tramadol is legally available in Qatar. I'm sorry, I could not find whether you can bring it in.


  https://www.sch.gov.qa/health-services/services-to-healthcare-professionals/pharmacy-n-drug-control/pharmacies-n-drug-control

Comment: Are you saying you have a prescription for it, and you are currently using it, and want to bring it in with you - or are you bringing it in for someone else?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can take Tramadol into Qatar.
BUT, you must have a prescription with your name and DOB on it + a letter from the prescribing doctor which details your need for the Tramadol, the dose, and how long you should take it.
Do not take any more than that mentioned in the letter, and in any event no more than 1-2 months supply.

Comment: +1 As its a controlled opioid; so without a prescription you cannot get it into the country.